# bash color change effect?

Tags: bash

I'm new at bash scripting and am writing a script to show battery status in i3blocks. I have a little lightning bolt glyph that indicates the battery is charging. I would like to have it so the color switches between green and another color. The code below outputs the green bolt glyph when charging, just stuck on how to make it alternate colors.

```
#! /bin/bash
bat=$(upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT1 | grep 
percentage | cut -c26-)
bat=$(echo "${bat//%}")
ac=$(acpi -a | cut -c12-)
warning="<span color='orange'><span font='FontAwesome'></span></span>"
red="<span color='red'><span font='FontAwesome'> Charge!</span></span>"
charged="<span color='green'><span font='Monaco'>Charged!</span></span>"
bolt="<span color='green'><span font='FontAwesome'></span></span>"
boltz="<span color='black'><span font='FontAwesome'></span></span>"

if [ "$ac" == on-line ] && [ "$bat" -le 94 ]; then
  echo " $bolt" #this is where i want the color to switch
elif [ "$ac" == on-line ] && [ "$bat" -ge 95 ]; then
  echo "Charged"

else
  if [ "$bat" -ge 95 ]; then
    echo ""
  elif [ "$bat" -ge 70 ]; then
    echo ""
  elif [ "$bat" -ge 50 ]; then
    echo ""
  elif [ "$bat" -ge 30 ]; then
    echo "$warning"
  elif [ "$bat" -ge 10 ]; then
    echo "$red"
  fi
fi
```

Comment: i3blocks appears to follow the [**i3bar protocol**](https://i3wm.org/docs/i3bar-protocol.html) related to formatting. That 'may' include scripting with escape code input, you will just need to confirm. (many of the i3blocks scripts are written in perl, e.g. [**battery**](https://github.com/vivien/i3blocks/blob/master/scripts/battery))

Comment: I have used the battery script you refer to. I'm learning shell scripting and just wanted to take a stab at it. I tried using the escape code input. It worked fine in the terminal but not in the block.

Comment: Yes, it appears the color calls are specified in html notation, e.g. `#000000` form. I didn't follow it all the way through the i3block code, but it appeared that was what was wanted. There is also an `escape` function in the i3block code using `fprintf`, but it did not appear to be looking for ANSI escapes for colors.